# How to identify polylines with multiple end/starting points?

Tags: arcobjects, geometric-network

I'm looking for a way to programmatically identify polyline features which do not represent a 'simple' line from A to B but instead have several starting and/or end points. These are called complex network edges when working with geometric networks.

Why am I asking this? Because I have a geometric network with a feature class that is defined as only having simple network edges. But it somehow occurred that there are some 'bad' (i.e. complex) edges in there as well and I need to sort them out. Checking if the interface IComplexEdgeFeature is implemented doesn't work on the feature objects because by definition all features within that class are simple edges.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "bad".  Do you mean multipart polylines?  If so, did you try finding polylines where IGeometryCollection.Count > 1 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try finding all polylines where [IGeometryCollection.GeometryCount](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/GeometryCount_Property/002m000001v7000000/) > 1.

I think [the example](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Calculate_Field_examples/005s0000002m000000/) for calculating vertex count could be adapted to do this with the field calculator.

Answer (score 2):

If the end points are not marked as such, you will have to find a definition that can unambiguously identify an end point. Depending on your geometry, that may be next to impossible, because an algorithm cannot tell whether the points

```
y
|  A B C D
+----------x
```

represent a simple line

```
A-B-C-D
```

or a polyline

```
A-B C-D
```

unless you have a clear criterion that can tell B-C is a bad edge.

If end points *are* marked, just choose a location in your algorithm where you have to iterate through all points anyway, and mark those geometries with more than two end points.

Comment: Are you claiming that ArcObjects cannot distinguish a disconnected polyline A-B C-D from the connected polyline A-B-C-D??

Comment: Well, theoretically your answer would be correct, I guess. The point of my question was - how do I do it with ArcObjects without extensive geometric calculations.